# Google Static Map Tile Location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to use something other than latitude and longitude for the Google staticmap center location. I would prefer pixel or tile coordinates. After reading the docs, it does not appear they support anything other than lat & lng.

What I am trying to do is display a series of static maps placed next to each other. I have everything working. However, using the longitude to offset the next staticmap in the sequences seems to offset it in the lat by a little bit. Meaning, if I only update the lng value it appears to shift in the lat as well.

In some cases, the image will not offset until a substantial change has been made to the lng.

### Example Code:

```
var lat = 40.714728;
var lng = -73.998688;
var size = 640;

for(var i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
{
  var addressLatLng = "("+lat+","+lng+")";

  var google_tile = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&center="+addressLatLng+"&zoom=20&size="+size+"x"+size+"&maptype=satellite";

  lng += 0.0005; // Does not shift up/down if using 0.0001 but also creates repeated visual data... needs a seamless transition from one tile to the next.
}
```

Is there a better approach for what I am trying to do?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you dont use a "real" map? I dont think that this approach would look pretty with the attributions on the bottom of each tile,

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The idea is to generate a single image by writing each tile to a single HTML5 canvas.

Creating a single large image will free the dependency of internet connectivity. This material will be presented in environments which may not provide online services.

Comment: I'm afraid this kind of usage is not permitted.